# Encrypt string into int in C#

Tags: c#-4.0, encryption

I have looked a lot on the internet, couldn't find what I needed. I found either string to string, or md5, which doesn't return an int and so on.

So what I need is a bit of guidance on how I could encrypt a string into an int. The framework I am working on is used for a while so I cannot change that.

At some point, I have a `UniqueID` property which should be the ID of an entity, but that sometimes is `null`, therefore I cannot use it, so I need to use other two ID-s to create a unique id, to assign to my `UniqueID`, something like `string.format("{0}-{1}", branchId, agentId)`, then encrypt this into int, assign it to `UniqueID` which gets sent to a whatever method, decrypt `UniqueID` back into a string, and split by "-" and get my two Ids. And to mention that I don't have any security worries. Grateful for your help.

Comment: How long is the string? Should it be a single integer? Note that hashing can NOT be reversed...

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd it has to be reversed, that is the whole point, and about the length...two ID-s, I don't think there will be more than 150.000 records in each table, so probably something like "150.000-150.000"

Comment: I doubt whether or not you are using the term `encryption` correctly. If feels as if you are trying to generate a unique ID, not an encrypted string.

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd I have an AgentId and a BranchId that come from the database, let's say AgentId is 142038 and BranchId is 129982. I have a property UniqueID which is int. so I have to do something like this: int myID = TransformSomehowThisStringIntoInt(string.format("{0}-{1}, AgentId, BranchId)); UniqueID = myID; MyMethod(UniqueID); void MyMethod(int uniqueID) { string agentAndBranchIDs = TransformSomehowBackThisIntIntoString(uniqueID); split the string by "-", first is AgentID, second is BranchID }

Comment: UniqueID has to presumably be unique among all these "entities", so how is it currently being set? You mentioned it can be null, so is it an instance of a specific class, an object, a nullable int? I assume you compare it for equality at some point, so how do you do that? Can two objects have the same branchId and agentId? If not, can either one be duplicated? When you say int, does it definitely have to be 32 bits?

Comment: @jerry The way I get them is not important at this point, plus I said in the main post, I cannot change anything in the framework, otherwise I would have done that. The whole thing is that I need to convert the string that would look like the example into an Int32 and back. That is all...

Comment: Not possible unless you are talking a very limited number of different characters in very short strings. e.g. branch_ID * 256 + agentID, so you have 0 - 2 ^15 to play with for both. You could if you said a-z pack a char into 5 bits and get ooh six characters. Can't represent 150,000 in four bytes without losing something.

Comment: @bokkie my point is that if you can't change the framework, it's already setting some UniqueIDs, and they have to be unique, you'd have to know how it's being set to avoid generating duplicates. Anyway, you've got a bigger problem: you're trying to stuff 22,500,000,000 strings into an int that can hold 2,147,483,648 (or 4,294,967,296 if you allow negative numbers)

Comment: @TonyHopkinson then what is the longest string that I could represent in an int32?

Comment: If you want to be able to encode any arbitrary values for `branchId` and `agentId` and you want their ranges to be equal, you'd have to restrict them to 65,536 distinct values (32,768 if you need UniqueID to be non-negative). If you're talking any arbitrary string (in .Net parlance, code points 0000-FFFF), you get two characters. If it's strictly 7-bit ASCII, four or five characters.

Comment: @jerry so then it is not possible. Agents and Branches are tables in my db. Cannot tell the user to add max 99 of each :). I estimated about 150.000 records for branches. So the maximum string would have had 13 characters: "123000-142000"

Comment: As @Jerry says four bytes = four chars , two for each. If they are numbers so represented by 0-9, you could go up to 8 chars overall (packed BCD) and get two four digit numbers in there, dash is unnecessary

Comment: @TonyHopkinson of course dash would be necessary, otherwise where would I split the string when I decrypt it?

Comment: No, dash is not necessary. If you make your ids always have 6 characters (i.e. use leading 0's). So agent id 34 and branch id 26 would be `00003400026`. And you split at the sixth character.

Comment: eh? first two bytes of the int is branchid, last two is agentId...

Comment: @bokkie you misunderstood, you'd only have the 4 (really more like 4.57, but the fractional part's interpretation isn't very intuitive) character limit (and hence the need to limit the values to 99 each) if you were trying to encode all ASCII characters. There are some tricks you might use, but it sounds like they don't apply to your case (and the core concept would probably leave your code inflexible and brittle in any case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're asking can't be done, in general. You have two numbers, each of which can range from 0 to 150,000. It takes 18 bits to represent 150,000. So it would take 36 bits to represent the two numbers. An `int32` is 32 bits.

Unless you can exploit some special knowledge about the relationship between branches and agents (if there is any), then it will be impossible to squeeze those 36 bits into a 32 bit integer.

You could, however, create a lookup table that assigns a unique key to each branch-agent pair. A simple incrementing key. You could then build the pair (i.e. `142096-037854') and look up the id. Or, given the id, look up the branch/agent pair.

Comment: being the first answer, I will accept this one and give it the vote, thanks for making things more clear.

Answer (score 0):

If there's a way to compress two 18 bit numbers into 32 bits, I sure don't know of it. If you can't be sure that the two ID's can be under 65536 (or one of them under 16384) then the best I can come up with is for you to change UniqueID to a long - then it's straight forward, no strings, just put AgentId into the first 32 bits and branchId into the last 32 bits.

Comment: thanks, but as I mentioned before, that UniqueID damn property is part of the framework I work with and cannot change it, it has been used like that for a long time. Otherwise I would have made it string and wouldn't have needed this whole story...thanks anyway